# Задать относительный путь в проекте ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть проект на ASP MVC с именем Test. 
В проекте есть папка App_Data в которой файл testFile.xml, к которому нужно обратиться.

```
 XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load("Test/App_Data/testFile.xml");
```

пробовал и такие варианты:

```
document.Load("../App_Data/testFile.xml");
document.Load("~/App_Data/testFile.xml");
```

Но это всё неправильно.

Господа, собственно вопрос, как правильно прописать?

Comment: `document.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/testFile.xml"));`

Comment: Igor, спасибо, так работает!

Comment: @Igor оформите как ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

переменная `Sever` может быть недоступна, лучше использовать `HostingEnvironment.MapPath(_virtualPath)`. Переменная `Server` берет метод именно отсюда.

Comment: У вас ответ неполный. Пожалуйста, пишите такие ответы, чтобы ими можно было воспользоваться независимо от других ответов.

Answer (score 2):

```
var xmlFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/cult.xml");
```

---

```
/App_Data
```

В эту папку вы кладете закрытые данные,
такие как XML-файлы или базы данных,
если вы используете SQL Server Express,
SQLite или другие файловые хранилища.
IIS не будет обрабатывать
содержимое этой папки.

Или если есть доступ к Контроллеру, то

```
string xmlFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/cult.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Для преобразования виртуального пути в физический в ASP.NET - используйте `Server.MapPath`:

```
document.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/testFile.xml"));
```